# How to deal with Auto Width property for labels in Reports Devexpress?

Tags: devexpress, label, xtrareport

Am designing simple report in Devexpress. I add three labels continuously in xtrareport. 1st label & last label are set in designer screen but middle label data comes from database it may be (big or small) word or sentence. If data comes from database big means 3rd label get overlap with this data. How to solve this ?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**0. Three labels.**
In report designer set the width of you 2nd label as more as possible:
[image: Width of 2nd label]

Set the `CanShrink`, `CanGrow`, `Multiline` and `WordWrap` to `true`:

```cs
xrLabel2.CanShrink = true;
xrLabel2.CanGrow = true;
xrLabel2.Multiline = true;
xrLabel2.WordWrap = true;
```

In result you will get something like this:
[image: The result]

**1. One label with special format.**
You can use one label with format string. Use `{0}` as placeholder for your data source values:

```cs
xrLabel1.DataBindings.Add(new XRBinding("Text", null, "Value", "Here is the text: «{0}». Here is the end."));
```

[image: Label with format string.]

Also you can set the `CanShrink`, `CanGrow`, `Multiline` and `WordWrap` to `true`.

The result will be something like this:
[image: Result with one label]

**2. One label with [brackets] in the labels's text.**
You can insert a data field name with [brackets] into the control's text. For example:

```cs
xrLabel1.Text = "Here is the text: «[Value]». Here is the end."
```

[image: Label with [brackets]]

And here is the result:
[image: Result with [brackets]]

Comment: Hi @nempoBu4, Thanks for your answer. This above example working fine, but I don't want that empty space in short sentence or word. eg Label 1 **Peter**, Label2 **is** & Label3 **a Doctor**  here why i need so much of space after **is** ? also if the case Label 2 have big sentence contain three to four words means, Label2 to wanna grow its width and Label3 wanna move after Label2.

Comment: @SriHari I have added another approach to my answer. You can use one label with special format instead of three labels.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time. That's working fine.

Comment: i Have one more doubt. This above process is working fine only when we have one data that comes from database. In a case i need to bind two or three data that comes from database in a single line means again get overlap with next column. Its possible to solve this ?

Comment: @SriHari You need to insert a data field name with [brackets] into the control's text. For example: `xrLabel1.Text = "Here is the name: [Name], here is the some text: [Text]"`.

Comment: Hi @nempoBu4 its possible to format like font size or bold or italic or time only a particular data fields ?? In my case i have one datetime field it showing like **28-05-2015 00:00:00**  i need to show date only **28-05-2015** and also am displaying total amount currently it showing 15900 but i need to set font **bold** and **"n2"** format like **15,900.00**. Its possible to set in a particular label ?? Again very much thankful for your time.

Comment: @SriHari This is the new question. Post it as a new question in StackOverflow.